# Строка не добавляется пустая, а данные не сохраняются. Объясните почему

Tags: c#, sql-server

Не сохраняются введенные данные в DataGridView файл базы данные .mdf sql server'a. Не добавляется пустая строка в DataGridView

P.S. Помогите исправить , и объяснить почему так происходит

```
   using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace AdoNetWinFormsApp
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            DataSet ds;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
             string ConnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=L:\123\base.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    // делаем недоступным столбец id для изменения
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].ReadOnly = true;
                }

            }
            // кнопка добавления
            private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); // добавляем новую строку в DataTable
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            }
            // кнопка удаления
            private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // удаляем выделенные строки из dataGridView1
                foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
                }   
            }
            // кнопка сохранения
            private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                    commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateUser", connection);
                    adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name"));
                    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Age"));

                    SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    adapter.Update(ds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```